# Key name in associative array

Tags: javascript, jquery, associative-array

I'm trying to add items to an associative array but my key name is not being generated properly. My code is as follows:

```
var room_name = $('#room_name').val();
var item_name = $('#item_name').val();
var item_description = $('#item_description').val();
roominventory[room_name] = { item_name : item_description };
```

What is happening is I am getting

```
{
    "Correct room name": {
        "item_name": "correct item description"
    }
}
```

Everything works except the `item_name`. I would like the key name to be the value of `item_name` but instead I'm just getting the text `item_name`.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use variables in the object key with the syntax you're using, as they are taken literally. You need to use bracket notation as you are in the setter of `roominventory`. Try this:

```
var room_name = $('#room_name').val();
var item_name = $('#item_name').val();
var item_description = $('#item_description').val();

var obj = {};
obj[item_name] = item_description;
roominventory[room_name] = obj;
```

Comment: Thanks Rory that works a treat. I wasn't aware they were taken literally. I can see now how your solution overcomes this problem.

Thanks again,

Clint

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can use

```
roominventory[room_name] = {[item_name] : item_description};
```

Comment: I didnt know this was possible (and I first had to check it to believeI ). I frequently use the kind of solution showed by the other answers and till now I thought it was the only way do to it, but I prefer the yours, much more simple and readable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Rory pointed out, you can't use variables in key. you have to use an `object` which holds the `key and value`:

```
//wrong one
var roominventory = {};
var room_name = "something";
var item_name = "something item";
var item_description = "something description";
roominventory[room_name] = {item_name : item_description};
console.log(roominventory);

//correct way
var roominventory1 = {};
var room_name = "something";
var item_name = "something item";
var item_description = "something description";
var obj = {};
obj[item_name] = item_description;
roominventory1[room_name] = obj;
console.log(roominventory1);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u2j42wsv/

Comment: If I already pointed it out, why add another identical answer?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: i was working on the fiddle in that time... no offense to your answer.. if wanted will delete.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var room_name = $('#room_name').val();
var item_name = $('#item_name').val();
var item_description = $('#item_description').val();

roominventory = new Array();
roominventory[room_name] = {};
roominventory[room_name][item_name] = item_description;
```